# Pass uuid to reverse() to construct url

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a url:

```
url(r'^profile_detail/(?P<uuid>%s)/$' % uuid, ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name="profile_detail_view")
```

And I need to redirect a user to that view, but I don't know how to construct the url without hardcoding it, which I don't want to do.

I figured something like:

```
reverse('profile_detail_view' 'profile.uuid')
```

And I tried some variations of that, but I didn't get it right. I also tried something with args and kwargs, but nothing.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**urls.py**
In `urls.py` you only define patterns that – when matched – call the given view. What has been matched will be passed to the view as named argument, e.g.

```
url(
    r'^profile_detail/(?P<uuid>[\d\-]+)/$', 
    ProfileDetailView.as_view(), 
    name="profile_detail_view"
)
```

This pattern will match digits (`0-9`) and the hyphen (`-`) (depending on the `uuid` you can strengthen the regex in terms of grouping and length).

**view**
It is then the responsibility of your view to look up the user that this `uuid` belongs to (or raise an error if no user was found), e.g.

```
class ProfileDetailView(View):
    def get(self, request, uuid):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(uuid=uuid)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404  # or whatever else is appropriate

        # ...
```

**reversing**
Reversing the view works by passing everything necessary to the `reverse` function. The key in `kwargs` needs to match the named regex in your url pattern `(?P<uuid>[\d\-]+)`

```
reverse('profile_detail_view', kwargs={'uuid': profile.uuid})
```

Comment: Damn, I was close :) I forgot to put uuid param name in quotes in kwargs when I was trying that out... I had it like this: ... kwargs={ uuid: profile.uuid} ...

Comment: I just wanna add something here that uuid's pattern is like `[\w]{8}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{12}`.

Comment: @AliBZ that can also be simplified to `(?P<uuid>[0-9A-Za-z\-]+)` just my $.02